# Is there an event for when the title attribute shows the tooltip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip, event-listener

So, let's say I have this span with a `title` attribute:

```html
<span title="Tooltip" id="mySpan">Span</span>
```

This shows the tooltip just fine, but I'd like to attach some kind of event listener for when the title shows with either JavaScript or JQuery. e.g. something like (obviously `"title"` isn't a valid event):

```
document.getElementById("mySpan").addEventListener("title", function () {
    console.log("Tooltip shown");
});
```

---

I know that I could create my own tooltip with JavaScript and a `mouseover` event like this:

```js
document.getElementById("mySpan").addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    console.log("Tooltip shown");
    document.getElementById("myTooltip").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("myTooltip").style.top = (event.clientY + 5) + 'px';
    document.getElementById("myTooltip").style.left = (event.clientX + 5) + 'px';
});

document.getElementById("mySpan").addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    document.getElementById("myTooltip").style.display = 'none';
});
```

```css
#myTooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: lightgray;
    padding: 2px 4px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span id="mySpan">Span</span>
<span id="myTooltip" style="display: none;">Tooltip</span>
```

But this means I have to recreate the style of the `title` attribute from scratch, which changes from browser to browser, and from OS to OS, and I'd really rather not change the standard tooltip that the user is used to seeing.

---

So, in summary, is it possible to attach some sort of event listener for when the `title` attribute displays?

Comment: No, there is no related event :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: this isn't actually an event listener.

It's not the greatest of solutions, but it works. All it does is start a `setTimeout` for 0.5s (that was based on trial and error, couldn't find it in any docs) on `mouseover`, and cancel it when you `mouseout`. It works for me, but it might not work if the delay changes based on the browser / OS.

```js
var titleShowTimeout;
document.getElementById("mySpan").addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    titleShowTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log("Tooltip shown");
    }, 500);
});

document.getElementById("mySpan").addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    clearTimeout(titleShowTimeout);
});
```

```html
<span title="Tooltip" id="mySpan">Span</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery-ui **Tooltip Widget**

```js
$( document ).tooltip();  
$("#inputhelp").tooltip({
    open: function( event, ui ) {
     console.log('Text tooltip');
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<p>
  <a href="#" title="Anchor description">Anchor text</a>
  <input id="inputhelp" title="Input help">
</p>
```

Comment: That's actually a pretty good solution for the JQuery tooltip, however, I was really hoping for an answer to the `title` attribute itself.