{point.name] find and replace string in the name before rendering
I have this code:
tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    pointFormat: '<b>{point.name}:</b> {point.value}'
                },

and I would like to replace a string within the point.name before it's shown to the user.  How do I do this?

Are you talking about the JS code or the chart? Could you elaborate please?

Some options:

If you are looking for an event to register that a tooltip may be shown on an HTML element, there really isn't one (as noted in this answer referenced below), but this answer recommends the jQuery "tooltip" widget that could then handle it programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47315566/23744626
Pre-process the CSS file itself as it is served from the web server.
Point the tooltip text to a HTML element or attribute that has the appropriately processed text. So instead of "point.Name" you could use another attribute that is already formatted as you need it for that element.

